# how can i get stylus working with xampp and autocompile the .styl files?

Tags: xampp, localhost, stylus

Hi i've been looking for some time for this simple answer.

I've already installed node.js and stylus and got to compile with cmd the .styl file into css... now my question is how can i make it work with xampp.

I want to be able to edit my .styl file and see the result in my localhost/whatever.

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a real noob question but i've been searching and finding no answer.